# Suggestion on writing Chapter Number in some beautiful, creative and interesting way.

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I am writing an expository book for myself(It is just some notes which I want to convert into electronic format).  I have divided it into chapters.

I have this idea in my mind.

Instead of writing

**Chapter $0$**

I think it will look more beautiful("mathematically beautiful") and *aesthetically pleasing* if I write

**Chapter $e^{i\pi}+1$**

Any suggestions for other numbers. I have around $12$ chapters excluding Chapter $0$.

P.S. Kindly correct the tags, if they are not OK.

Comment: It's not aesthetically pleasing to me

Comment: https://www.zazzle.com/math_wall_clock-256361090792439656 (found by googling on "math clocks" and asking for images, which gives tons of examples)

Comment: Why not name the chapters after important mathematicians and  something about them ? (Riemann's Hypothesis, Godel's Incompleteness,  ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some sites that are effectively museums of numbers, which should offer plenty of inspiration:

[What's Special About This Number?](https://erich-friedman.github.io/numbers.html)

[Number Gossip](http://www.numbergossip.com/)

[The Secret Lives of Numbers](http://turbulence.org/Works/nums/)

[Notable Properties of Specific Numbers](http://www.mrob.com/pub/math/numbers.html)

[Zoo of Numbers](http://www.archimedes-lab.org/numbers/Num1_69.html)

[The Database of Number Correlations: Properties and Meanings](http://www.virtuescience.com/number.html)

[Wikipedia's Integers Category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Integers)

[Prime Curios](http://primes.utm.edu/curios/index.php)

[The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/)